# JUnit tests kills daemon

Tags: java, junit, daemon, watchservice

I'm creating a daemon that watches a given directory for changes. When it detects changes it runs all the tests using JUnit that are present in the directory.

It does this by invoking

```
    private void runTestsInWatchedDirectory(){
    TestRunner runner;
    runner= new TestRunner(this.dir);
    org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(runner.getClass().getName());
}
```

with TestRunner being an small adaptation from this code: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=52.

It correctly finds and runs all tests, but when it is done, the daemon is terminated! I know JUnit kills child threads, but why does the daemon die? And how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JUnitCore.java](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java), you can see that `JUnitCore#main` calls `System.exit()`:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Result result = new JUnitCore().runMain(new RealSystem(), args);
    System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Use one of the other methods in the class, or copy the code from runMain:

```
Result runMain(JUnitSystem system, String... args) {
    system.out().println("JUnit version " + Version.id());

    JUnitCommandLineParseResult jUnitCommandLineParseResult = JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(args);

    RunListener listener = new TextListener(system);
    addListener(listener);

    return run(jUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(defaultComputer()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was it. Since I develop my project alongside JUnit, I've chosen to adjust the visiblity of runMain as a solution.